# Hibernate many to many with an additional column without changing HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

In the existing project we have a many-to-many relationship, it turned out that now we need to keep the time when that connection happed. The following approach has been used
https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Now we have these classes (the names are just taken from the link above):

```
@Embeddable
public class PostTagId
    implements Serializable {
 
    @Column(name = "post_id")
    private Long postId;
 
    @Column(name = "tag_id")
    private Long tagId;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "post_tag")
public class PostTag {
 
    @EmbeddedId
    private PostTagId id;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("postId")
    private Post post;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("tagId")
    private Tag tag;
 
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn = new Date();
}

@Entity
public class Tag {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "post",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PostTag> tags = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Since it is a big project and there are tons of places to change, the Post class still has methods like getTags, setTags, removeTags, etc.

```
List<Tag> getTags() {
   return tags.stream().map(PostTag::getTag).collect(collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(), Collections::unmodifiableSet))
}

void addTag(Tag tag) {
   tags.add(new PostTag(this, tag, new Date())
}
```

It allows to hide from the outer world that collection is changed from <Tag> to <PostTag>. The problem happens with buzillion HQL queries that we have at the moment, since smth like this won't work:

```
...
JOIN post.tags t
WHERE t.name = <?>
```

Because "t" is now PostTag and not Tag, hence t.name is trying to access an unknown field

Are there any ways to mitigate that problem? Add some annotations above PostTag, so that instead of accessing tag.name hibernate will do t.tag.name, use other ways of mapping, etc.

Comment: I don't know about something. Why don't you simply change your queries?

Comment: First, there are lots of them. Secondly, potential merge conflicts. Query won't raise a compile time error, it'll just sit in the code and throw an exception in runtime. The problem getting even worse, since other teams use the jar with that model